# What can I do about water coming in from underneath when it rains?

Tags: foundation

I live in a newer home. when it rains really hard and  a lot water comes in and soaks my carpets.I can feel the walls wet. I don't have gutters or any leaks around window. I already had that checked. somebody said water statics. what do i do if it is ? I would love any help

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare. I guess you are finding out that "dry" is better than "new". The guy across the street from me gets his basement flooded every time it rains and mine is dry as a bone. Isn't that funny?

Comment: It sounds like to me they didn't put a drain tile in when they built the home. As @TylerDurden said ... NIGHTMARE.

Comment: If you had the house built, check your paperwork to see if you have any sort of a new home warranty. Sounds like they really messed something up.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Is this a basement?  What walls are wet?  The drywall or the concrete?  You don't have any gutters on your house?  What is water statics?

Comment: Is there a sump pump for the home?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to identify the source of the water.

You don't have gutters. If rainwater runs off your roof and splashes onto the ground next to your walls I would consider installing guttering and leading the rainwater through pipework away from the house to a soakaway (large gravel filled pit).

If the surrounding ground slopes towards the house, I would consider installing something like a French-drain that intercepts ground water and directs it around the house to a point where the ground slopes away from the house. This is a big project and you need to be sure of what  is causing your problem before starting.

In both cases you probably need professional help or at least get someone experienced to come and look at the building.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this horrible problem depends on a lot of information you haven't told us (foundation type, climate, lot grading, etc), but regardless, this is a job for a pro, not something DIY-able. As described, your house sounds completely defective, especially if it is "newer." Here are some of the things you'll probably hear and may have to do:

1. Add gutters, either at the eaves or in the ground (in the form of gravel-filled trenches), and make sure they drain to a location far from the foundation
2. Excavate all around the perimeter of the house about 3 or 4 feet wide and install rigid XPS foam along the floor of the dug trenches (and vertically against the foundation walls if there's none already there), sloped outwards to redirect water that seeps into the ground away from the foundation, as well as perimeter drains above the XPS foam to carry bulk water away from the foundation
3. Backfill the trench with more impervious soil (e.g. more clay than sand)
4. Re-grade the soil around the house to slope away from the foundation
5. Jack up the house off the foundation and install a damp-proof course to prevent any rising moisture in the soil from entering the walls